# Examples of using the SDK to deploy Safe and perform transfer from wallet in one go?

Tags: transactions, transfer, safe-core-sdk, deploy

I'm assuming the optional **to** and **data** field on **SafeAccountConfig** object is used for this case? Can someone point me to docs or examples that demonstrate this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the **to** and **data** fields are used for safe module initialisation. The fields used for post-deployment transfers/payments are:
**paymentToken**, **payment** and **paymentReceiver**